# figuring out why custom-element is shown in safari and firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: polymer

I've tried to figure out why the custom element  is shown in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome. Neither in Canary nor in 35.0.1916.114.
Shadow dom is enabled in flags.

I've put together a fast jsBin:
http://jsbin.com/poracihi/4/

Comment: adding the js as a code snippet in line is going to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Chrome has native Shadow DOM support. You're seeing the effect of the shadow dom boundary preventing the page's styles from bleeding in. The solution is to include the styles inside your element's shadow dom: http://jsbin.com/poracihi/5/edit

Check out:
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/
- http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html